# Angular - test reactive form control enable on value changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have to test if some controls are enabled.

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
this.form.get('menuVisibility').valueChanges.subscribe((visible: boolean) => {
    ['userIdVisibility', 'userOptionsVisibility', 'languageVisibility'].forEach((controlName) => {
      if (visible) {
        this.form.controls[controlName].enable();
      } else {
        this.form.controls[controlName].disable();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I wrote this SPEC:

```
it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', fakeAsync(() => {
component.form.get('menuVisibility').setValue(true);
component.form.get('menuVisibility').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: true });
component.ngOnChanges();
tick();
expect(component.form.get('userIdVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
expect(component.form.get('userOptionsVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
expect(component.form.get('languageVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

But the test never enters in the forEach block.

Comment: DId you tried by adding `fixture.detectChanges();`

Comment: This code is a memory leak. You add a subscription every time ngOnChanges is called. Please move the code to ngOnInit. You only need to subscribe once. And don't forget to unsubscribe.

Comment: I'm running fixture.detectChanges(); on beforeEach().

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MoxxiManagarm where it is a memory leak, I would move it to the `ngOnInit`.

For a quick unblock, try calling `ngOnChanges()` first before setting the value so the observable stream is subscribed before we change the values:

```
it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.ngOnChanges();
  component.form.get('menuVisibility').setValue(true);
  component.form.get('menuVisibility').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: true });

  tick();
  expect(component.form.get('userIdVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
  expect(component.form.get('userOptionsVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
  expect(component.form.get('languageVisibility').enabled).toBeTruthy();
   }));
```